# iPad and iPhone can sync with each other on Notes -- how about adding info on the Mac or PC?

Tags: data-synchronization, notes.app

Right now the iPad and iPhone can sync with each other for any Notes added or edited, so one note added on the iPad will go to the iPhone automatically, and I think this is done by sync'ing with the Gmail account.  How about when using the Mac, if there is additional info, is there a way to add it to the note on the Mac (or on PC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lion, iPad and iPhone notes that are synced through your mail account can be accessed and edited in Apple's Mail app.

Comment: it works, thanks.  but can we edit on gmail or google docs (using a browser)?  that's because nowadays, i tend to access email just using browser and not download any email to a Mac or PC any more

Comment: You can view your notes on gmail, but unfortunately I don't think you can edit them because gmail treats the notes as normal mail.